# How to Add an Exception to a SQL 'Quality Check' Rule?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have the following query:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.FUND, B.MANAGER_NAME, C.FUND, C.MGR_NM
FROM TABLE_1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B ON  
            A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE C ON
A.FUND = C.FUND
WHERE 
B.MANAGER_NAME != C.MGR_NM
```

The results of this query show when a Manager is incorrectly assigned to a fund.

The `REFERENCE_TABLE` is the source of truth and shows the correct `FUND` and `MGR_NM` assignments.  However, I need to add one exception to this rule: when `FUND = 'BOSTON'`, it's okay if `MANAGER_NAME` = 'Kim, John, or Danny'.

All other funds have a 1:1 relationship between fund and manager name.
How can I add this exception to my query?

Comment: One way is to create a Y/N flag with a case expression, removing a WHERE altogether and then selecting from it. There are probably slightly shorter ways, but this would be a way to easily identify and read your exceptions. Or just modify your WHERE with your AND/OR criteria.

Comment: Whats is "query alert me"? Null in JOINed fields? Try ``LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B ON  
            A.ID = B.ID or (FUND = 'BOSTON'  and  MANAGER_NAME in( 'Kim', 'John','Danny')``

Comment: @ValNik this change alone will not return the expected results.

Comment: @Chris Schaller, thanks for comprehensive answer to this question.

Answer (score 3):

> Show all results where `MANAGER_NAME` does not match `MGR_NM`, unless the `FUND` is  'BOSTON', ***then*** it is okay if `MANAGER_NAME` is one of 'Kim, John, or Danny'

Sounds like a case for a simple `OR` expression in your criteria, but we need to invert the match on 'Kim, John, or Danny' and return if the fund is 'BOSTON' and the `MANAGER_NAME` is NOT one of 'Kim, John, or Danny'

But it's not too simple, be careful when injecting `OR` operator into your criteria though, if you are not using brackets to separate the logical expressions in the criteria then `OR` will compare either side of the operator independently which can produce undesirable results.

In the following solution no brackets are used, but we have to evaluate a non-match for the `BOSTON` fund in the original logic so that 'Kim', 'John', 'Danny' are not considered valid for other funds:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.FUND, B.MANAGER_NAME, C.FUND, C.MGR_NM
FROM TABLE_1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE C ON A.FUND = C.FUND
WHERE 
A.FUND <> 'BOSTON' 
AND B.MANAGER_NAME != C.MGR_NM
OR A.FUND = 'BOSTON' 
   AND B.MANAGER_NAME != C.MGR_NM 
   AND B.MANAGER_NAME NOT IN ('Kim', 'John', 'Danny')
```

You might prefer to use brackets to make the expression more readable, or to highlight the exceptional case. The RDBMS is likely to expand the brackets on evaluation anyway so it shouldn't have an impact on performance either way, but it does allow us to use syntax like this if it is helpful:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.FUND, B.MANAGER_NAME, C.FUND, C.MGR_NM
FROM TABLE_1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE C ON A.FUND = C.FUND
WHERE 
B.MANAGER_NAME != C.MGR_NM
AND (
    A.FUND <> 'BOSTON' 
    OR A.FUND = 'BOSTON' 
       AND B.MANAGER_NAME NOT IN ('Kim', 'John', 'Danny')
    )
```

---

While this should work, the question is *why are 'Kim', 'John', 'Danny' valid?* If `REFERENCE_TABLE` is the source of truth then you could allow multiple entries for each fund in this table, then you wouldn't need to hardcode the specific case for 'BOSTON' at all and we can use an `OUTER JOIN` to return only the non-correlated rows:

```
SELECT A.ID, A.FUND, B.MANAGER_NAME, C.FUND, C.MGR_NM
FROM TABLE_1 A 
LEFT JOIN TABLE_2 B ON A.ID = B.ID
LEFT OUTER JOIN REFERENCE_TABLE C ON A.FUND = C.FUND 
                                  AND B.MANAGER_NAME = C.MGR_NM
WHERE 
C.FUND IS NULL
```

This works because all the valid manager will match and will have a non-null value for `C.FUND`. However all rows that do not find a corresponding match in the `REFERENCE_TABLE` will have a value of `null` for `C.FUND`, these are the rows that we want to see.

Comment: Thank you Chris, the brackets example is exactly what I'm looking for.  And your follow-up question is valid...I'm actually debating this with other stakeholders now.  In a perfect world, there is a 1:1 relationship between fund and manager but I have one fund that requires multiple managers as it's size is dramatically larger than the others.  It's more of an organizational chart issue, that gets pushed down to me.  Thanks again for your help

Comment: A well designed schema should cater for _exceptions_, it shouldn't force you to hard code special data cases like this. Even if 99% of Funds only have a single valid manager, `BOSTON` is the only proof you need that conceptually the relationship is 1:n. 100% of records satisfy this relationship. Don't try to fight it. Over time more data exceptions will evolve for the same reasons (or others) as this one. Fixing it now may save you lots of time and money later, but will also make this logic repeatable and testable in another environment. You are testing right? ;)